# Do I need to add anything to proguard rules when upgrading to java 8?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

After changing my gradle file from

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

to

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

I'm getting a warning when using proguard

```
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
     You probably need to update the library versions.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
```

Is there something I need to add to my proguard rules for java 8?

EDIT: found the issue.  Seems like proguard does not like ConccurentHashMap.  Added this to my proguard file:

```
-dontwarn java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
```

Comment: Try updating proguard to 5.2 or latest.
The version now in sdk is 4.7 or 4.8 I guess.
May be it will solve the problems.